# Is there anyway to change xticks in a plot with a data frame table?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: Line plot with table as the xticks or xlabel]

Hey guys I was wondering if there is a way to change xticks in a plot with pandas data frame? I recently see this line chart that instead of the regular xticks, it has dataframe or table as the xticks. Can we do this by using matplotlib or seaborn? Check the picture to see the line chart. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matplotlib there is such a possibility:
[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744354/matplotlib-create-table-data-for-one-row-multiple-columns), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138482/matplotlib-bar-plot-with-table-formatting), [matplotlib manual](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/misc/table_demo.html).

Try to replace the bar command by a plot command